# Terrafrom datasource aws_vpcs - count.index error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use data source aws_vpcs to get the vpc id having specific tag.

For reference:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpcs.html

Below is my terraform yaml file.
Terrafrom version used is: 0.12.3

```
data "aws_vpcs" "foo" {
  tags = {
    Name = "test1-VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "cluster" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids)}"
  vpc_id = "${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids)[count.index]}"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster-ingress-node-https" {
  description              = "Rule to do xyz"
  from_port                = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.cluster.id}"
  to_port                  = 443
  type                     = "ingress"
}
```

I am getting below error. Request for help to fix this

```
terraform plan

Error: Missing resource instance key

  on modules/eks/eks-cluster.tf line 40, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster-ingress-node-https":
  40:   security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.cluster.id}"

Because aws_security_group.cluster has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_security_group.cluster[count.index]
```

Comment: Do you actually have multiple VPCs tagged this way that you are trying to manage at the same time? If not you should use the singular `aws_vpc` data source and remove all the `count`s here.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list of `aws_security_group` as you are using count on the `aws_security_group` resource. The error even mentions it:

> Because aws_security_group.cluster has "count" set, its attributes
>   must be accessed on specific instances.

So either you need to include count on the `aws_security_group_rule` resource and create one `aws_security_group_rule` for each `aws_security_group` created, or in the case you expect only one VPC to be returned, create only one `aws_security_group` by accessing the returned `aws_vpcs.foo.ids` with index 0.

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to get the security group id by using as below

security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.cluster.0.id}

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the list of security group.
Terraform provides flatten function to do that https://nedinthecloud.com/2018/07/16/terraform-fotd-flatten/
You should not get this error afterwards

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used flatten, but will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a while ago. Stumbled upon this issue.

`${aws_security_group.cluster.*.id}` should do it.

Since the `resource aws_security_group` is creating multiple security groups with count, resource block `aws_security_group_rule` needs to reference the correct index in the list.